# Specific example of Norm vs. Metric on a sequence space

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ the space of all real sequences and let $d$ be the metric defined by
$$d(x,y) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}}2^{-k}\frac{|x_k-y_k|}{1+|x_k-y_k|}.$$

I have proven that for a sequence $x = (x^{(n)})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ with $x^{(n)} \in X$ we have
$$d(x^{(n)},0) \to 0 \iff x_j^{(n)} \to 0 \;\;\; \forall j \in \mathbb{N}.$$

My question is the following: Does there exist a norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $X$ such that there exist positive numbers $c, C \in \mathbb{R}$ with
$$c\|x\| \leq d(x,0) \leq C\|x\| \;\;\; \forall x \in X$$

Comment: ... giving therefore a kind of equivalent distances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is clear that for any numbers $a$ and $b$, we have
$$
\frac{|a-b|}{1+|a-b|} \leqslant 1,
$$
and consequently,
$$
\forall x,y\in X,\quad d(x,y) \leqslant \sum_{k\in \Bbb N} 2^{-k} = 2.
$$
(Note that I use the convention $0\in \Bbb N$).
Therefore, if such a norm would exist (with $c>0$, which is what you presumably want), this would imply that
$$
\forall x \in X,\quad c\|x\| \leqslant d(x,0) \leqslant 2,
$$
and finally, we would have
$$
\forall x \in X,\quad \|x\| \leqslant \frac{2}{c}.
$$
This is obviously impossible since norms are homogeneous and hence unbounded.

Another way to say that is the following: $(X,d)$ cannot be bi-Lipschitz equivalent to $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ for any norm $\|\cdot\|$, since $(X,d)$ is bounded, but $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ isn't.